# How to remove the space between two macros only when they immediately follow another?

Tags: macros, spacing, vertical-spacing

I use the following layout where the `\sec{}` headers are placed in the margin and `\subsec{}` headers and text paragraphs are position in the main column next to it.

However, when a `\subsec{}` immediately follows `\sec{}`, I would like both to start on the same line without vertical space. The issue is that I can't just include negative space in one of the commands because `\subsec{}` should still create spacing when it follows anything other than `\sec{}`. How can I achieve this?

Here is a small example that shows the unwanted space, where I would want SECTION and Subsection to start on the same line and keep all other spacing as it is:

[image: unwanted space between sec and subsec]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setlength{\parskip}{.5em}
\setlength{\parindent}{0em}

\newcommand{\titlecol}{1.45in}
\newcommand{\titlesep}{0.5em}
\newcommand{\secskip}{1.6em}
\newcommand{\subsecskip}{0.6em}

\renewcommand{\sec}[1]{%
  \vspace{\secskip}\hspace{-\titlecol}%
  \parbox[t][0pt][t]{\titlecol-\titlesep}{#1\raggedright}}

\newcommand{\subsec}[1]{\vspace{\subsecskip}\textbf{#1}\par}

\begin{document}
\begin{adjustwidth}{\titlecol}{0em}

\sec{SECTION}

\subsec{Subsection}
\lipsum[1][1-2] \par
\lipsum[1][3]

\subsec{Subsection}
\lipsum[1][1-3]

\sec{ANOTHER SECTION}
\lipsum[1][1-3]

\end{adjustwidth}
\end{document}
```

Comment: you are dropping everything which allows to control the behaviour, e.g. your sectioning commands will allow page breaks between the heading and the text. Better use e.g. a package like titlesec to setup the sectioning commands. The documentation shows on page 22 and example of a margin heading.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I spent a whole day trying to use `\titlesec` but `leftmargin` didn't work and `drop` had a similar issue to the one described in my question here. I opened a question about it but gave up this route because it was too complex and hard to find help. You can see the solution below, which uses `\nopagebreak` to prevent the issue you described.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following plain TeX macro defines `\sec` in such a way that the section heading is typeset as part of the first paragraph in the section (so no page break can intervene):

```tex
\def\sec#1{\vskip\secskip
  \noindent\llap{
  \setbox0=\vtop{\hsize\titlecol\advance\hsize by-\titlesep\raggedright#1} 
  \dp0=0pt\box0\hskip\titlesep}\ignorespaces}
```

This allows you to omit the vertical skip before a subsection if you are already in a paragraph, that is, contribute a vertical skip only in vertical mode:

```tex
\def\subsec#1{\ifvmode\vskip\subsecskip\fi\textbf{#1}\par}
```

But you must then avoid a blank line between `\sec` and `\subsec`, because that would end the paragraph started for the section so that the subsection contributes a vertical skip:

```tex
\sec{SECTION}
\subsec{Subsection}
```

Comment: That looks promising! Could the blank line between `\sec` and `\subsec` be allowed through something like `\ifvmode\vspace*{-\baselineskip}\fi` or `\@ifnextchar\par\@gobble\relax`?

Comment: Adding `\@ifnextchar\par\@gobble\relax` after `\ignorespaces` might work, please try it out.

Comment: (A line with a single `%` on it does not count as blank.)

Comment: Fantastic, that works! I wrote up the complete solution here, based on your approach (which turned out to be the simplest of the answers): https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/656233/61219

Answer (score 7):

You can set the title text, then return to the vertical mode, then correct the vertical position by a set of `\vskip`s and then put a `\penalty` with a special (non-breakable) number (10013 in the example).

If the `\subsec` follows then you can read this number by `\lastskip` and put (or not) a `\vskip` above the `\subsec`:

```
\parskip=.5em
\parindent=0em

\def\titlecol{1.3in}
\def\titlesep{0.5em}
\def\secskip{1.6em}
\def\subsecskip{0.6em}
\hoffset=6cm
\hsize=12cm

\def\sec#1{%
  \vskip\secskip
  \hskip-\titlecol
  \vtop {\hsize=\dimexpr\titlecol-\titlesep\relax \rightskip=0pt plus1fil\relax #1\vss}
  \par
  \nobreak \vskip-\prevdepth \prevdepth=0pt \vskip-\baselineskip \vskip-\parskip
  \penalty10013
}

\def\subsec#1{\ifnum\lastpenalty=10013 \else \vskip\subsecskip\fi {\bf#1}\par\nobreak}


\sec{SECTION}

\subsec{Subsection}
\lipsum[1]\par
\lipsum[2]

\subsec{Subsection}
\lipsum[1]

\sec{ANOTHER SECTION}
\lipsum[1]
```

Edit: I try to explain the code in more detail. The `\sec` macro puts a `\vtop` on the left side (with one or more lines) as a part of single-line paragraph finalized by `\par`. The second and more lines in the `\vtop` are accumulated in the depth of it. If we put a next material after the `\par`, the material will be after it, i.e. after the last line of `\vtop`. The `\prevdepth` is TeX register (can be used only in vertical mode) where we can read or set the depth of the last box put to the vertical mode, i.e. this `\vtop` in our example. `\vtop-\prevdepth` returns the current typesetting point at the baseline of the first line of the `\vtop`. We set it to zero after using its because placing of next box in vertical mode is calculated from `\baselineskip` or `\lineskip` depending on `\prevdepth`. We want to use `\baselineskip` and we return the typesetting point by `-\baselineskip` in order the baseline of the next box will be the same as the baselines of `\vtop`. But next paragraph adds `\parskip` too, so we must to put the negative `\parskip` too.

The `\rightskip=0pt plus1fil\relax` is similar to `\raggedright` but the glue at the right side is infinitely stretchable so it is excluded that the words hyphenation is started (because we don't want such hyphenation in titles).

Comment: Great, that works! The idea of setting the penalty in `\sec` and reading it in `\subsec` is intuitive to me, can this not be integrated into my example more easily? For example, what is the `\prevdepth` and the `\rightskip=0pt plus1fil\relax` for? I'm sure your rewrite is better than my initial version, I'd just like to make sure I understand it so that I can learn something and also to make modifications to it in the future.

Comment: OK, I added an explanation of the code.

Answer (score 4):

This assumes you never start the section text with `{`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setlength{\parskip}{.5em}
\setlength{\parindent}{0em}

\newcommand{\titlecol}{1.45in}
\newcommand{\titlesep}{0.5em}
\newcommand{\secskip}{1.6em}
\newcommand{\subsecskip}{0.6em}

\renewcommand{\sec}[1]{%
  \par
  \addvspace{\secskip}\hspace{-\titlecol}%
  \makebox[\titlecol][l]{\parbox[t][0pt][t]{\titlecol-\titlesep}{#1\raggedright}}%
  \subsecfalse
  \checksubsec
}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\checksubsec}[1]{%
  \ifx#1\par
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
  {\checksubsec}% found \par, repeat
  {\checksubsec@#1}% check for \subsec
}
\newcommand{\checksubsec@}[1]{%
  \ifx#1\subsec
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
  {\subsectrue\subsec}% found \subsec set the conditional to true
  {#1}% reinsert the token
}
\makeatother
\newif\ifsubsec
\newcommand{\subsec}[1]{%
  \ifsubsec\else\par\addvspace{\subsecskip}\fi
  \textbf{#1}\par\nobreak
}

\begin{document}
\begin{adjustwidth}{\titlecol}{0em}

\sec{SECTION}

\subsec{Subsection}
\lipsum[1][1-2] \par
\lipsum[1][3]

\subsec{Subsection}
\lipsum[1][1-3]

\sec{ANOTHER SECTION}
\lipsum[1][1-3]

\end{adjustwidth}
\end{document}
```

The first token is looked at (ignoring spaces). If it's `\par` we discard it and repeat; if it's `\subsec` we set the conditional to true and issue `\subsec` again. Otherwise the token is reinserted and typesetting goes on.

I made a few changes: the section title is set in a box of the appropriate dimension and the `\parbox` with a reduced width (by `\titlesep`) is set inside it; I added `\nobreak` so sections or subsections are not detached from the following text.

You should better use `geometry` and actually set the section titles in the margin, rather than faking this with a global `adjustwidth`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I'm trying out all the answers now and will accept the one that works best soon. The tip about `\nobreak` is much appreciated. I tried using geometry initially but I didn't figure out how to change the margins mid-way into a page, which is needed in my case for an intro paragraph without title that should span the full with.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot to Heiko Theißen for suggesting to typeset the `\sec` inline as part of the paragraph and then checking in `\subsec` whether we're already in a paragraph to only otherwise (`\ifvmode`) insert the vertical space.

I also used `\@ifnextchar\par\@gobble\relax}` to prevent empty lines after `\sec` to start a new paragraph, which requires wrapping the `\sec` definition in `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`. The `\ignorespaces` didn't seem to be necessary anymore since we're already ignoring paragraph breaks.

In addition, I switched from the pure TeX solution to LaTex `\parbox` that I'm more familiar with, making it easier to understand and modify the solution for me. Thanks also to egreg for suggesting the `\nobreak`/`\nopagebreak` to prevent sections from detaching from following paragraphs.

```
\makeatletter
\def\sec#1{%
  \vskip\secskip%
  \noindent\llap{\parbox[t][0pt][t]{\titlecol-\titlesep}{\raggedright#1}}%
  \nopagebreak\@ifnextchar\par\@gobble\relax}
\makeatother
 
\def\subsec#1{%
  \ifvmode\vskip\subsecskip\fi%
  \textbf{#1}\par\nopagebreak}
```

Full example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setlength{\parskip}{.5em}
\setlength{\parindent}{0em}

\newcommand{\titlecol}{1.45in}
\newcommand{\titlesep}{0.5em}
\newcommand{\secskip}{1.6em}
\newcommand{\subsecskip}{0.6em}
 
\makeatletter
\def\sec#1{%
  \vskip\secskip%
  \noindent\llap{\parbox[t][0pt][t]{\titlecol-\titlesep}{\raggedright#1}}%
  \nobreak\@ifnextchar\par\@gobble\relax}
\makeatother
 
\def\subsec#1{%
  \ifvmode\vskip\subsecskip\fi%
  \textbf{#1}\par}

\begin{document}
\begin{adjustwidth}{\titlecol}{0em}

\sec{SECTION}

\subsec{Subsection}
\lipsum[1][1-2]\par
\lipsum[2][1-3]

\subsec{Subsection}
\lipsum[1][1-2]

\sec{ANOTHER SECTION}
\lipsum[1][1-3]

\end{adjustwidth}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]