# How to correct vertical spacing after multiple side-by-side parboxes?

Tags: spacing, line-spacing, vertical-spacing, parbox

I use a `\dated` macro to put a date at the end of the line with some text left of it, using two `parbox`.

When the text uses only a single line, the spacing underneath this construct looks fine. But when the text left to the date takes up multiple lines, there is not enough vertical space after the two parboxes. I think it might be because the spacing is computed based on the parbox that has the date in it, which is not necessarily as tall as the parbox for the text.

How can I create the same vertical spacing between the left parbox and the text underneath it?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\datesep}{0.5em}
\setlength{\parindent}{0em}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}

\renewcommand{\fboxsep}{-\fboxrule}

\newcommand{\dated}[2]{%
  \fbox{\parbox[t]{\linewidth-\widthof{#1}-\datesep}{#2\raggedright}}%
  \fbox{\parbox[t]{\widthof{#1}+\datesep}{\normalfont#1\raggedleft}}}

\begin{document}

\dated{2022}{\textbf{\lipsum[1][1]}}
\lipsum[1][4-6]

\dated{2022}{\textbf{\lipsum[1][1-3]}}
\lipsum[1][4-6]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a similar idea as in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/656142/255231:

```tex
\newcommand{\dated}[2]{%
  \fbox{\vbox{\setbox0=\hbox{\kern\datesep\fbox{\strut #1}}
  \advance\hsize by-\wd0
  \noindent\rlap{\hskip\hsize\box0}\strut#2\strut\par}}}
```

But I am unsure how exactly you want the `\fbox`es to align. You should at least insert `\strut`s so that they leave room for ascenders and descenders.

Answer (score 0):

Heiko's answer mostly worked, I just had to insert `\hsize\linewidth` for it to respect custom line widths (to be used with `changepage`) and swapped `\vbox` for `\vtop` for the alignment that was needed in my case (to play nice with [margin titles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/656138/how-to-remove-the-space-between-two-macros-only-when-they-immediately-follow-ano/656142#656142)).

```
\newcommand{\dated}[2]{%
  \vtop{\setbox0=\hbox{\kern\datesep\normalfont\strut#1}
  \hsize\linewidth\advance\hsize by-\wd0
  \noindent\rlap{\hskip\hsize\box0}{\strut#2\strut\par}}}
```

This avoids the inconsistent spacing that `\parbox` or `\minipage` would insert.